# Pandas: Find immediate following duplicate record and sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Working with an online data set where a user upload an item to sell but immediately take it down and I only want to identify the the entries which are immediately following the same original entry.

```
activityTime       customerId  itemId activityType  dollarValue
2000-01-01-10:23        101     p101        add        10.32   
2000-01-01-10:25        101     p102     remove        10.32
2000-01-03-11:45        101     p102        add        10.32
2000-01-04-11:46        101     c101        add        11.00
2000-01-03-09:32        300     c201        add        69.34
2000-01-03-13:33        300     c301        add        23.54
2000-01-04-15:12        300     c401        add        79.25
2000-01-04-15:16        300     c401     remove        79.25
2000-01-05-16:32        300     c401        add        79.25
```

Goal is to get following records from above:

```
2000-01-01-10:25        101     p102     remove        10.32
2000-01-04-15:16        300     c401     remove        79.25
```

Remove columns can't be trusted therefore here are the steps that I carried out:

```
dups = df[df.duplicated(['customerId', 
                           'itemId', 
                           'dollarValue'], 
                          keep=False)]
```

Then separate out by `activityType`

```
df_add = dup[dup.activityType == 'add']
df_remove = dup[dup.activityType == 'remove']
```

Then merge by these keys assuming things would line up correctly but it didn't and things ended up lining up with the same item add after the removal.

```
df_add_remove = pd.merge(
    df_add, df_remove, 
    on=['customerId', 'itemId', 'dollarValue'], 
    how='inner'
).filter(['customerId',
          'activityTime_x', 
          'activityType_x',
          'activityTime_y', 
          'activityType_y', 
          'dollarValue']).rename(
    columns={'activityTime_x':'addDateTime',
             'transactionDateTime_y':'removeDateTime'}
)
```

The remove item should exist immediately after added item within few minutes. This item could be added by the customer again in a later date.

It looks like merge is not a good approach here whats the best pythonic / pandas way to do this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.activityTime = pd.to_datetime(df.activityTime)
df =  df.sort_values(['customerId','itemId','activityTime'])
def filter_product(x):
    if 'remove' in x['activityType'].values:
        x['diff_in_sec'] = (pd.to_timedelta(x.activityTime - x.activityTime.shift(1)).dt.total_seconds())
        return x[(x['activityType'] == 'remove') & (x['diff_in_sec'] < 600)]
removed_df = df.groupby(['customerId','itemId']).apply(filter_product).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Had a slightly different problem if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67459880/pandas-find-repeat-edits-consecutive-all-consecutive-edits-have-happened-in

Comment: I am seeing time_dff as negative values should this shift(1) should take the record after the current record?