# Pandas: Find repeat edits (consecutive) - all consecutive edits have happened in small time window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Working with a data set where users are uploading documents and editing the documents. Goal is to identify repeating / consecutive edits that are identical.

To qualify as a consecutive repeating edit, the edit must be done by the same user, same document within a small time window, type of the edit should be `edit` and `wordsAdded` should be same.

```
editTime               userId   docId     editType  wordsAdded
2000-01-01-13:23:12        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:00        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:10        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:11        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:25:00        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:25:13        101     p101       edit        10
2000-01-01-13:24:14        101     p101       edit        1
2000-01-01-15:28:12        101     d101       upload      00
2000-01-01-15:30:00        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:01        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:04        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-01-15:30:10        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-01-15:30:11        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-03-11:45:01        101     p102       edit        44
2000-01-04-11:45:03        101     c101       edit        44
2000-01-03-09:32:04        300     c201       edit        05
2000-01-03-13:33:05        300     c301       edit        04
2000-01-04-15:12:06        300     c401       edit        19
2000-01-04-15:12:10        300     c401       edit        19
2000-01-05-16:32:08        300     c401       edit        32
```

In the above data set the valid consecutive edits are:

```
2000-01-01-13:23:12        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:00        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:10        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:11        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:25:00        101     p101       edit        05

2000-01-01-15:30:00        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:01        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:04        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-01-15:30:10        101     p101       edit        12

2000-01-04-15:12:06        300     c401       edit        19
2000-01-04-15:12:10        300     c401       edit        19
```

My approach for this was:

Convert the time to epoch:

```
df['editTime'] = df['editTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S").timestamp())

multi_edits = df[df.duplicated(
    ['userId', 
     'docId', 
     'wordsAdded', 
     'editType'], 
    keep=False)].where(
    df.editType == 'edit').sort_values(
    ['userId','docId', 'editType', 'editTime']
)
```

In order to get the time span added a method:

```
def time_span(df: pd.DataFrame):
    df['time_diff'] = df['editTime'].diff(1)
    return df
```

Then Group by the `multi_edits` to get the total consecutive edits and word count

```
multi_edit_sum_count = multi_edits.groupby(
    ['userId', 
     'docId', 
     'wordsAdded', 
     'editType']).apply(time_span)

multi_edit_30s = multi_edit_sum_count[
    multi_edit_sum_count.time_diff < 30].agg(
    {'wordsAdded':'sum', 'userId':'count'})
```

I don't think this is the accurate approach. Also there might be a better approach in pandas to do this.

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for just the total duplicate edits which occurred within 30seconds of each other and the number of unique users?

Answer (score 1):

We can write some logic which checks if the time difference is max 60 seconds (you can edit this to your needs) and if the group is more than 1 row:

```
def check_time_difference(s):
    fill_value = pd.Timedelta(0)
    m1 = s.diff().fillna(fill_value).dt.seconds.le(60).all()
    m2 = s.shape[0] > 1
    
    return m1 & m2


grp_cols = ["userId", "docId", "editType", "wordsAdded"]
df[df.groupby(grp_cols)["editTime"].transform(check_time_difference)]
```

**Output**

```
              editTime  userId docId editType  wordsAdded
0  2000-01-01 13:23:12     101  p101     edit           5
1  2000-01-01 13:24:00     101  p101     edit           5
2  2000-01-01 13:24:10     101  p101     edit           5
3  2000-01-01 13:24:11     101  p101     edit           5
4  2000-01-01 13:25:00     101  p101     edit           5
8  2000-01-01 15:30:00     101  d101     edit           2
9  2000-01-01 15:30:01     101  d101     edit           2
10 2000-01-01 15:30:04     101  p101     edit          12
11 2000-01-01 15:30:10     101  p101     edit          12
12 2000-01-01 15:30:11     101  p101     edit          12
17 2000-01-04 15:12:06     300  c401     edit          19
18 2000-01-04 15:12:10     300  c401     edit          19
```

Comment: so `s` is a row right, since this is getting called in groupby level? or s is `s: pd.DataFrame`

Comment: getting a `TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`