# 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed - Using in a Groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Goal is to identify repeating / consecutive edits that are identical.

To qualify as a consecutive repeating edit, the edit must be done by the same user, same document within a small time window, type of the edit should be edit and wordsAdded should be same.

```
editTime               userId   docId     editType  wordsAdded

2000-01-01-13:23:12        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:00        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:10        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:11        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:25:00        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:25:13        101     p101       edit        10
2000-01-01-13:24:14        101     p101       edit        1
2000-01-01-15:28:12        101     d101       upload      00
2000-01-01-15:30:00        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:01        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:04        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-01-15:30:10        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-01-15:30:11        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-03-11:45:01        101     p102       edit        44
2000-01-04-11:45:03        101     c101       edit        44
2000-01-03-09:32:04        300     c201       edit        05
2000-01-03-13:33:05        300     c301       edit        04
2000-01-04-15:12:06        300     c401       edit        19
2000-01-04-15:12:10        300     c401       edit        19
2000-01-05-16:32:08        300     c401       edit        32
```

Expected Output:

```
2000-01-01-13:23:12        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:00        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:10        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:24:11        101     p101       edit        05
2000-01-01-13:25:00        101     p101       edit        05

2000-01-01-15:30:00        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:01        101     d101       edit         2
2000-01-01-15:30:04        101     p101       edit        12
2000-01-01-15:30:10        101     p101       edit        12

2000-01-04-15:12:06        300     c401       edit        19
2000-01-04-15:12:10        300     c401       edit        19
```

I had a solution but didn't feel like my solution was getting the right results. But got a different solution from Stackoverflow. Unfortunately I am getting `'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Here is the solution obtains with the help of Stackoverflow Member: ([original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67459880/pandas-find-repeat-edits-consecutive-all-consecutive-edits-have-happened-in))

```
def check_time_difference(s):
    fill_value = pd.Timedelta(0)
    m1 = s.diff().fillna(fill_value).dt.seconds.le(60).all()
    m2 = s.shape[0] > 1
    
    return m1 & m2


grp_cols = ["userId", "docId", "editType", "wordsAdded"]
df[df.groupby(grp_cols)["editTime"].transform(check_time_difference)]
```

Comment: The given solution returns the expected output without any errors. What's exactly your question?

Comment: When I am executing on the data set i get the mutable error

Comment: It's not happening with your sample data. Is your actual data **exactly** the same with the sample (columns, data type)?

Comment: re-checking it.

Comment: Only difference is that time is in `2016-07-14 03:57:47` where as when i typed above `2016-07-14-03:57:47` has a hypen. And I have converted the time column  `apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))` since there was a Character

Comment: ok slight change words_added is a float there are decimal points but floats are immutable objects

Comment: @QuangHoang `Length mismatch: Expected axis has 885665 elements, new values have 8 86363 elements` any reason why would i get this? I think mutable issue got fix